# CI3.1.6 and HMVC modules::load not working on Debian / Windows does

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

I have the following problem with CodeIgniter 3.1.6 and WireDesignz HMVC.

When using modules::load on a windows dev machine (using Apache etc) its working, but when uploaded to my Debian machine it ain't working.

```
$class = modules::load('page/Page');
var_dump($class);

if (method_exists($class, '_DoAction'))
{
    //More shizzle
}
```

It's gives me NULL with var_dump on Debian, while in Windows it's continues with inside the IF loop.

The folder structure of the modules directory is as follow

/plugins/page/controllers/Page.php and the class is called Page.

The folder plugins is in web root and the System and Application directory is outside the web root.

Anyone a clue ?

**Edit**: looks my routes are also not working.

**Edit 2**: Looks like something is not correct with my development Debian installation, because pushing the code to another Linux server, it is working! Also it's only HMVC that aint working.
It's there some log where I can find errors ?

Comment: Windows isn't case sensitive... Linux is Very Case Sensitive - check your case of your controllers and models etc...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw : I have the controller filename as Page.php and the class name is also Page. It's in the directory /plugins/page/controllers. So to me it looks good, but could be wrong.